# Spring security configuration does not work on HTTP POST request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to secure my urls in the following way:

posting to "/user/": only those that are **not** logged in

all other requests should be logged in

this is my config class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    //auth method omitted for brevity

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean //replace with bcrypt later
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public UserShallowDTO getUser(Authentication auth) {
        return new UserShallowDTO(); //just an empty object with null properties for testing purposes
    }
    
    // @PreAuthorize("!isAuthenticated()")
    //@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse> AddUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        // stuff here
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String PostTestMethod() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The problem is it keeps returning 401 error on postman when I POST.
However, when I change the config to GET rather than POST, the get method of the controller works as intended.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to `CSRF`. By default `CSRF` is enabled in `Spring`.
you can disable it in your configuration method.

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
  }
```

Reference: [Spring Security CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure)